# Every line parallel to $l$ to another line parallel to $l$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that if $T$ carries a line $l$ to $l$, then it also carries every line parallel to $l$ to another line parallel to $l$.

I got stuck since a line is not a vector subspace if it does not contain $(0,0)$. Is their anything I am doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the $\ell$ line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\vec{p}+t\vec{v}$, where $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{p},\vec{v}\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Then by assumption, 
$$
T(\vec{p}+t\vec{v})=\vec{p}+t\vec{v}\implies T(\vec{p})+tT(\vec{v})=\vec{p}+t\vec{v}\implies T(\vec{v})=\vec{v},\;T(\vec{p})=\vec{p}
$$
by equating coefficients.

Taking a line parallel to $\ell$ as having the same direction vector, but different starting point, i.e. $\vec{q}+t\vec{v}$, we have 
$$
T(\vec{q}+t\vec{v})=T(\vec{q})+tT(\vec{v})=T(\vec{q})+t\vec{v}
$$
which is another line parallel to $\ell$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really misunderstood the question.